# in django how to display all videos in static folder in a single page

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to built a page which will display all the videos in static folder and able to play them (not just listing the video file name).

## UPDATE 2:

view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os 

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    path="D:\\servers\\my_django\\src\\static\\"  
    video_list =os.listdir(path)   
    return render(request,'index.html', {'videos': video_list})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
{% load static %}
    {% for video in videos %}
    <video width="320" height="240" preload controls>
        <source src="{% static video %}" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using os.walk(dir_path) which lists all files inside a directory. then replace the file path with your static url path and render in html.

Comment: thank you it worked. now i have a new problem a cannot seek the video .

Comment: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: post the code of how your seeking the video in your html

Comment: @PavanKumarTS i have put code in update 2 section in the main post

Comment: in your browser developer console elements search for any source src and open link in new tab to see if the URL path is able access the resource

Comment: @PavanKumarTS when i open the src in new tab the video start downloading

Comment: Thats may be browser not supporting video try different browsers. if the issue persists may be the video mime type is not properly served to the player.

Comment: i am not able to forward or backward my video in any browser

Comment: why dont you try some opensource media players like https://videojs.com/ and others which help you to solve problems with docs.

Comment: even videojs.com could not help my

Comment: https://github.com/vinaykumar571999/my is my repo can you check it out